# Syntax highlighting for DataScience SE

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

The Data Science SE site requires syntax highlighting feature as the posts contain code from multiple languages/syntaxes including but not limited to Bash, Regex, Python, Julia, Java, R.

We collected a list of some posts which would benefit from this feature [here](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2367/11097).

PS: I am one of the moderators of that site.

Comment: Is my memory faulty thinking you can already add a language for syntax highlighting to tags ?

Comment: @Tensibai The syntax highlighting feature has to be enabled first by CMs, and then moderators can set languages for tags (and `<!-- language: -->` hints are available to users in posts)

Comment: (+1) This is really needed as it's available on other SE sites..

Comment: @Aurora0001 indeed, missed the post on my site meta asking for it :)

Comment: Since you are a mod, did you try asking in chat, e.g. the Teachers' Lounge, for a CM to enable it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I did. I was suggested to post here

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't see why this post is a dupe of the one linked, cause an answer by you literally says 'Post here on MSE if it's also relevant for other sites.' :)

Comment: @Dawny33 I meant "if it's relevant for several sites". Your request is very specific to one single site, so that site meta is the perfect place to ask for that. CMs also browse these, so can't see any reason why it should be here instead. If one, for example, asks "enable this for all sites related to food" (just example), then it fits here, since it's not a specific site. Anyway.. even closed, SE staff can still see it, and enable the syntax highlight. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Although it has been discussed explicitly(?!) I did not figure out whether it is going to be added or not, I guess it is really needed.

Comment: @Media SE developers are busy 200% these days with the SO for Teams projects, so hard to believe they'll have time for those requests any time in the near future.

Comment: @Media no, it requires moving JS files around... probably via very complicated system behind the scenes, as they have to keep 170+ code repositories for each site's custom JS.